# Processes used in quant finance

Tags: stochastic-processes, fx, brownian-motion, sde

What are the **main stochastic processes** (and their SDE) used in quant finance?
For example to model currency prices, stock prices, etc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a short list *(to be edited and improved - community wiki)* :

- [Standard brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion) (also called Wiener process) for which:
  $d\, W_t \sim  \mathcal N(0, \sqrt{d t})$
- [Geometric brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion), used in the [Black-Scholes model (1973)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model):
  $d\,X_t = \mu X_t\,dt + \sigma X_t\,dW_t$
- [Constant elasticity of variance ("CEV") model (1975)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_elasticity_of_variance_model):
  $d\,X_t=\mu X_t dt + \sigma X_t\,^\gamma\, d W_t$, with $\gamma \geq 0$
- [Orstein-Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process), with mean reversion property, used e.g. in [Vasicek model (1977)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasicek_model):
  $d\, X_t = \theta(\mu - X_t) dt + \sigma\,dW_t$
- Merton jump diffusion process (1976), used for options pricing:
  $d\, X_t = \mu X_t\, dt + \sigma X_t\, d W_t + y_t\, d N_t$, with $N_t$ a Poisson process, and $y_t$ the jump size as a random process
- [Cox–Ingersoll–Ross ("CIR") process (1985)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model), used for interest rates model:
  $d\, X_t = \kappa (\theta - X_t) dt + \sigma \sqrt{X_t} dW_t$
- [Heston model (1993)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heston_model), in which the volatility of the asset is not constant but follows a random process:
  $d\, X_t = \mu X_t dt + \sqrt{\nu_t}\, X_t\, dW_t^X$
  $d\, \nu_t = \kappa (\theta - \nu_t) dt + \xi \sqrt{\nu_t} dW_t^\nu$ (i.e. $\nu_t$ is a CIR process),
  with $W_t^X$, $W_t^\nu$ two Wiener processes with correlation $\rho$

  *Other processes that use a random process for volatility: $\nu_t$ follows a geometric brownian motion (Hull and White, 1987), $\nu_t$ follows a Orstein-Uhlenbeck process (Stein and Stein, 1991).*

See also [Modern Pricing Models](http://fedc.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/tutorials/stfhtmlnode52.html).

Comment: CGMY (http://www.math.nyu.edu/research/carrp/papers/pdf/jbarticle.pdf), time changed Levy (generalized Heston) (http://faculty.baruch.cuny.edu/lwu/papers/timechangeLevy_JFE2004.pdf)

Comment: @user9403 Is there a way to describe the idea behind these models in a few words? Can they be described as solution of a SDE like the other processes listed here? What are the relevant SDE for this processes?

Comment: These are Levy models which are defined by their characteristic function.  It is possible to write the infinitesimal generator as well.  However as far as I know there is no good way to write the SDE as the jump process may contain infinite jumps in finite time.

Comment: Ok @user9403. For the purpose of Monte Carlo simulation, do we have something that offers the same simplicity of a SDE, allowing to compute `X[i+1]` from `X[i]`, `X[i-1]`, etc. ?